# Service Broker received an error message on this conversation

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, trigger, service-broker, integration

I will first have to say, I am still trying to wrap my brain around all the components of the Service Broker and how they work together, so it's very likely I'm missing something obvious... it's just not obvious to me.

A little summary: We have a report server that has replicated transaction information from a POS system that we are trying to export in "real time" (the battle of real-time versus regular checks and exports via scheduled task and synchronous procedures has been fought and lost) to a web service that will run analytics and event based activities based upon the data in the transaction.

To this end, I created a Service Broker system for asynchronous web service consumption.  Here is what I did (not necessarily in order, sorry):

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dcmeta.[TriggerMessageSchemaCollection]
    AS 
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema id="TriggerMessageTypeSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/TriggerMessageTypeSchema.xsd"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/TriggerMessageTypeSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/TriggerMessageTypeSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
    <xs:element name="triggerMessage" nillable="false">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="schema" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="object" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="recordIds" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="recordId" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>';

CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [TriggerMessage]
    VALIDATION = VALID_XML WITH SCHEMA COLLECTION dcmeta.TriggerMessageSchemaCollection;

CREATE CONTRACT [TriggerContract]
(
    TriggerMessage SENT BY INITIATOR
);

CREATE SERVICE [TriggerInitiationService]
    ON QUEUE dcmeta.TriggerQueue
    (
        TriggerContract
    );

CREATE SERVICE [TriggerTargetService]
    ON QUEUE dcmeta.TriggerQueue
    (
        TriggerContract
    );

CREATE PROCEDURE dcmeta.[spProcessTriggerData]
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

begin
    declare 
        @message_type sysname,
        @dialog uniqueidentifier,
        @message_body xml,
        @schema sysname,
        @object sysname,
        @workflow_id int;

    while (1=1) begin -- forever loop
        waitfor(
            receive top(1) 
                @message_type = cast(message_type_name as sysname),
                @message_body = cast(message_body as XML),
                @dialog = conversation_handle
            from
                dcmeta.TriggerQueue
            ), timeout 500

        if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0 or @message_body is null) break;

        select
            @schema = mb.n.value('schema[1]', 'sysname'),
            @object = mb.n.value('object[1]', 'sysname'),
            @workflow_id = ap.WorkflowID
        from
            @message_body.nodes('.') as mb(n)
        inner join
            dcmeta.ApiWorkFlows ap
            on ap.[Schema] = mb.n.value('schema[1]', 'sysname')
            and ap.[Object] = mb.n.value('object[1]', 'sysname');

        if (@schema is null 
            or @object is null 
            or @workflow_id is null 
            or @workflow_id <= 0) break;

        insert into dcmeta.ExportedRows
        (
            [Schema],
            [Object],
            [RowId],
            [ScheduleWorkflowEventId]
        )
        select
            @schema,
            @object,
            mb.n.value('.', 'numeric(17)'),
            dbo.StartDcWorkflow(@workflow_id) -- this is the CLR UDF that calls the data collection webservice and returns a job id that can be tracked later
        from
            @message_body.nodes('//recordIds/recordId') mb(n);          

        end conversation @dialog;
    end
end

CREATE QUEUE dcmeta.TriggerQueue
    WITH STATUS=ON,
    ACTIVATION(
        PROCEDURE_NAME=dcmeta.spProcessTriggerData,
        MAX_QUEUE_READERS=10,
        EXECUTE AS SELF
    );
```

With this infrastructure in place, I create a trigger on my transactions table like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[DC_Insert]
    ON [dbo].[transact]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        declare 
            @message_body xml;

        select
            @message_body = (
                select
                    'dbo' as [schema],
                    'transact' as [object],
                    cast(
                        (select 
                            * 
                        from 
                            (
                            select distinct
                                i.trans_no as recordId 
                            from 
                                inserted i
                            ) as recordIds
                        for xml path(''), 
                            root('recordIds')
                        ) as xml)
                for xml path('triggerMessage')
            );

            if @message_body is not null begin
                declare @handle uniqueidentifier;
                begin dialog conversation @handle
                    from service TriggerInitiationService
                    to service 'TriggerTargetService'
                    on contract TriggerContract
                    with encryption = off;
                send on conversation @handle
                    message type TriggerMessage(@message_body);
            end

    END
```

To test this, I insert a row into my `dbo.transact` table, and look for results popping up on the other side of the webservice, but nothing shows up.  So, following some suggestions on figuring out what went wrong, I look up the following data:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.transmission_queue;
select * from sys.conversation_endpoints;
```

...which returns the following information:

```
conversation_handle to_service_name to_broker_instance  from_service_name   service_contract_name   enqueue_time    message_sequence_number message_type_name   is_conversation_error   is_end_of_dialog    message_body    transmission_status priority
37E6E8F2-A948-E411-A431-402CF4F3BB1A    TriggerTargetService        TriggerInitiationService    TriggerContract 2014-09-30 13:59:10.043 0   TriggerMessage  0   0   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ervice Broker received an error message on this conversation. Service Broker will not transmit the message; it will be held until the application ends the conversation.   5

conversation_handle conversation_id is_initiator    service_contract_id conversation_group_id   service_id  lifetime    state   state_desc  far_service far_broker_instance principal_id    far_principal_id    outbound_session_key_identifier inbound_session_key_identifier  security_timestamp  dialog_timer    send_sequence   last_send_tran_id   end_dialog_sequence receive_sequence    receive_sequence_frag   system_sequence first_out_of_order_sequence last_out_of_order_sequence  last_out_of_order_frag  is_system   priority
DCF00852-A545-E411-A431-402CF4F3BB1A    CFFA9BDB-41EC-48DE-B379-1AF7C2531551    1   2   DDF00852-A545-E411-A431-402CF4F3BB1A    2   2082-10-14 21:02:35.720 SO  STARTED_OUTBOUND    ExternalActivatorService    SiriusSQL   4   -1  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0   0x000000000000  -1  0   0   0   -1  0   0   1   5
37E6E8F2-A948-E411-A431-402CF4F3BB1A    2B4DAABB-A1FF-4ED3-961D-B4BCD0C5CC06    1   65541   38E6E8F2-A948-E411-A431-402CF4F3BB1A    65543   2082-10-18 17:13:16.997 ER  ERROR   TriggerTargetService    00E2A7ED-35EB-44DE-AB95-216799EA2BF4    1   -1  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1   0xB41300000000  -1  0   0   0   -1  0   0   0   5
```

... the thing that I noticed immediately was the `transmission_status` column saying the following:

```
Service Broker received an error message on this conversation. Service Broker will not transmit the message; it will be held until the application ends the conversation.
```

... but I don't know how to troubleshoot this further.  What is the error?  How can I localize it?  How can I fix it?  Any help pointing me in the right direction for answering any of these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running Profiler with the SSB events selected to see if that gives you any further information?

Comment: You have created your message type with mandatory schema validation, but I don't see that same schema being mentioned anywhere in the `FOR XML` generation query. Are you sure you need to tie the knot that tight?..

Comment: @RogerF.Wolf I technically don't have to.  I ended up removing that validation to see if it was the problem; it wasn't.  I do like the idea of having well-defined messages, though.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, when both initiator and target are under your complete control, `validation = valid_xml` is usually enough. Having this bit fixed, everything else should work as it is.

Comment: You are new to Service Broker, you say... the database should have `trustworthy` option set, and Service Broker should be enabled in it. And you might run into problems with the `execute as self` on the target queue - it might be better to try `as owner` first.

Comment: I had same situation and then I started looking at high level, I resolved it with a simple thing, make sure is your database owner should is an 'sa' or who is equivalent. I prefer to say and keep it to 'sa'. Hope this helps to someone facing the same issue.